# How to trim all the zeros value after decimal of the rounded value

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
declare @v nvarchar(50) = '21.89777777777777777777777777'
select convert(decimal(18,8),round(@v,3))
```

Unable to truncate the decimal values after rounded. eg in above question, it returns 21.8980000.

```
The resulting output must be like 
21.898 when rounded by select convert(decimal(18,8),round(@v,3))
and 21.8988 when rounded by  round(@v,4)
```

I have created an stored procedure from where i gets the round value. and it must trim the leading zeros after rounded. and It must be dynamic instead of changing the precision everytime

Comment: Use Float instead of decimal

Answer (score 1):

use a different precision for the `decimal`

```
declare @v nvarchar(50) = '21.89777777777777777777777777'
select convert(decimal(18,3),round(@v,3))
```

### [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/25074)

Answer (score 0):

The value is the same, regardless if it's `21.8980000` or `21.898`. It's the **format** that is different.

You should be formatting the value on the client, rather then on SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

Float will do your job

```
declare @v nvarchar(50) = '21.89777777777777777777777777'
select convert(float,round(@v,3))
```